# Capture argument passed to a function

Tags: unit-testing, go

In a unit test, I have created mock for the function *ExecuteDeleteQuery*

```
ExecuteDeleteQuery = func(deleteQuery string) ([]string, error) {
    return nil,nil
}
```

How can I capture the argument passed to this function and assert that?
I want to do something like:

assertEqual(t, deleteQuery, expectedDeleteQuery)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to capture one value, you can do something like this:

```
var gotDeleteQuery string

ExecuteDeleteQuery = func(deleteQuery string) ([]string, error) {
    gotDeleteQuery = deleteQuery
    return nil,nil
}

// ...

    assertEqual(t, gotDeleteQuery, expectedDeleteQuery)
```